# Laravel api 404 when try to call method from controller

Tags: laravel, routes

I have an application in `Laravel` deployed on the server. When I try to call `POST` in `Postman`:

```
http://api.mydomain.com/api/auth/signin
```

I get the error `404 not found`.

In file `RouteServiceProvider` I commented section for web:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
            /*
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
            */
        });
    }
```

When I had uncommented section for web and send `GET`from Postman but without any suffix, only domain: api.mydomain.com/ it worked.
Now I commented web and have only API section and any request to API method doesn't work.
My controller:

```
class JwtAuthController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
    */
    public function login(Request $request){
...
}
```

In `api.php` file:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/signin', [JwtAuthController::class, 'login']);
}
```

Result for `php artisan route:list`:

```
| App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api |
|        
| POST     
| api/auth/signin                                                             
| generated::1YOyMAVvTTnBZtym 
| App\Http\Controllers\JwtAuthController@login                        
| api
```

On my local machine, it works, but when I deploy it on the server it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not found because you did not add the subdomain `api`, To fix it

You can just remove `api.` from url, like that `http://exmaple.com/api/auth/signin`

#### OR

you can add the subdomain to `RouteServiceProvider`

like that

```
 Route::middleware('api')
    ->prefix('api')
    ->domain('api.exmaple.com') // <-
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

Comment: When I try in Postman with this url: `http://api.mydomaincom/auth/signin` I get 404, I added `->domain('api.mydomain.com')` and still the same error

Comment: @Mark did you clear the config?, you must remove `->prefix('api')` from `RouteServiceProvider` btw.